# Java Breadth First Search using Queue

Tags: java

I have build two classes in Java to traverse Breadth First Search. The `Node class` as:

```
public class Node {
  Node left;
  Node right;
  int value;

public Node(int value2) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  this.value = value2;
 }
```

The BreadthFirst Search `method` in `SerachClass`includes the following `code`

```
  public void breadthFS(Node root) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          Queue<Node> bfs=new LinkedList<Node>();

          if (root==null)
          {
              return; 
          }
          else 
          {
              bfs.clear();
              bfs.add(root);
              while(!bfs.isEmpty())
              {
                  Node current=bfs.remove();
                  System.out.println("The breadth first search"+current.value);
                  }
                  if (root.left!=null) bfs.add(root.left);
                  if (root.right!=null) bfs.add(root.right);
            }
          }
```

Then, I have inserted the following values {6,2,1,3,10,9,11}. The output will be in a loop such that:

```
The breadth first search 6
The breadth first search 2
The breadth first search 6
The breadth first search 2
The breadth first search 6
...
```

I will appreciate your help and comments.

Comment: So what's the problem?  You just dumped some code here without explaining why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mistake in your while loop:

rather than:

```
if (root.left!=null) bfs.add(root.left);
if (root.right!=null) bfs.add(root.right);
```

should be:

```
if (current.left!=null) bfs.add(current.left);
if (current.right!=null) bfs.add(current.right);
```

Comment: Opps!!... Thank you very much you get it. @Ivan Valeriani

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as correct.